# File upload is successful but file is missing in php

Tags: php, image, laravel, upload

I have this problem where the upload turns out successful but when i go to the directory of the upload the file isn't there...I did an **echo** on the **final_path** and thats exactly the directory I want the files to be uploaded.

```
$final_path=public_path('attachment\states');
$final_filename =  md5(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")).rand().'.png';

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $final_path/$final_filename))
{echo 'good'. $final_path; }
else
{ echo 'bad';}
```

the output is :

```
goodC:\xampp\htdocs\panel\public\attachment\states
```

whats wrong  ?

Comment: try : if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $final_path."\".$final_filename))

Comment: There is a division. Put the slash into quotes.

Comment: the backslash you used in the middle of the quotemarks  comments the rest of the code  $final_path."\".$final_filename

Comment: just a question, why don't you use the laravel methods?
https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#files

Answer (score 0):

This operation is performing division on the two strings, not giving you the path you expect.  In fact, the only reason you are not getting a divide-by-zero error is because `$final_filename` starts with a number.  Try this:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $final_path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $final_filename))
```

Comment: You are probably right! @MarlindParllaku was! It would also be worth mentioning that he does **absolutely no checking of `$_FILES['file']['error']`** always a good idea

Comment: It absolutely is, so +1 on that.  I mainly wanted to see the usage of `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` instead of a literal "/" or "\", since it seems like there's a mix between windows and non-windows systems in play here, for testing versus production.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use Laravel functions to move uploaded files. For example.

```
class MyController extends Controller{
    public function fileUpload(Request $request){
        if (!$request->hasFile('file')) {
            // file not received
        }

        if (!$request->file('file')->isValid()) {
            // file is not valid
        }

        $final_path = public_path() . "\attachment\states\\";
        $final_filename =  md5(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")).rand().'.png';

        $request->file('photo')->move($final_path, $final_filename);

        return 'File uploaded correctly';


    }

}
```